Why does Azure provide two resource names one with capitals one all lower case?
When creating managed Prometheus we see two "Azure monitor workspaces" listed in the managed Prometheus Tab inside Azure monitor.
One is camelCase:
"https://portal.azure.com#resource/subscriptions/*/resourcegroups/test-rg/providers/microsoft.monitor/accounts/test-name-workspace1"
The other is lower case:
"https://portal.azure.com#resource/subscriptions/*/resourceGroups/test-rg/providers/Microsoft.Monitor/accounts/test-name-workspace1"
Why do these two show up as separate resources, and can it mess up our deployment?



The reason you see two different resource names, one with camelCase and the other all lowercase, is due to differences in the resource naming conventions used in Azure. This distinction can occur because of how resources are created and managed within the Azure environment. Let me explain.
In case of CamelCase Resource Name-  The camelCase resource name typically indicates that the resource was created using Azure Resource Manager (ARM) templates or via Azure PowerShell or Azure CLI commands. ARM templates allow for more flexibility in naming resources, including the use of camelCase, PascalCase, or lowercase naming conventions.
For example, if you define the resource name as testNameWorkspace1 in your ARM template, Azure will create the resource with that exact casing.
On the other hand, in case of  Lowercase Resource Name- The lowercase resource name is likely the result of creating the resource through the Azure portal or using Azure Resource Manager directly. When you create resources through the Azure portal or ARM without specifying a specific casing, Azure may default to using lowercase for certain resource types or components of the resource name.
As for why these two different casings show up as separate resources, it's primarily due to how Azure manages and identifies resources internally. From Azure's perspective, resources with different casings in their names are distinct entities, even if they represent the same logical resource.

